# jQuery track down name of div by mouse pointer

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to store DIV name into variable when I hover over it?

Example:

`<div class="bar1">Text 1</div>

 <div class="bar2">Text 2</div>`

And when I hover over "Text 1", name of a DIV will be stored in jQuery variable. And when I hover to "Text 2" DIV name will be stored to variable.

`var class_name = $("");` DIV name stored in there

Comment: have you've tried this `<div class="bar1" onmouseover="myFunction('bar1');">`? or do you want to do it in some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure...

```
$('.bar1,.bar2').mouseover(function(event){
    var class_name = $(event.currentTarget).attr('class');
});​
```

...see it running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yy6bP/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Should be easy enough... give all elements you want to hover above the same class... then give them an ID to be differentiated by. Then use this JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hoverDivs').mouseover(function(){
        var elementId = $(this).attr('id');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do same using jQuery,

**HTML**

```
<div class="bar1" name="d1">Text 1</div>
<div class="bar2" name="d2">Text 2</div>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
 var name;
 var className;
    $("div").hover(function(){
     name = $(this).attr("name");
     className = $(this).attr("class");
     Console.log(name);
     //alert(name);
    });
​
```

---

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aFyrx/2/)**